# Virtual IP or Mac Binding IP for loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing, router, nat, virtual-ip, load-balance

I am configuring LoadBalancing for my website which is hosted on 2 webservers.
I have MAC binded static IPs for both the servers.
For LoadBalancer also can I have a MAC binded IP or a Virtual IP without any binding is mandatory?
I am referring to a physical load balancer. Mostly Cisco Router with LoadBalancing feature. .

Comment: Which Cisco product are you using? Any particular reason you are not using a http reverse proxy in front, as a load balancer?

Comment: I have the WebServer IP from different ISPs. So the IPs are from different subnets. The "http reverse proxy" means the NLB feature of windows OS? Iam not a networking guy, so checking.

Comment: This is the router iam checking the feasibility.     https://www.amazon.in/dp/B0814V1RZ9/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_i_ZbH9Eb12587DR   .  I will need https (SSL) throughout the request.

Comment: @JohnMahowald plz let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your definition of load balancing, it is more than inter-host services. For example, [HAProxy's intro document](https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.2/doc/intro.txt) defines load balancing broadly, including at the levels of link, network, and server.

Those WAN routers are for path redundancy to the Internet, hopefully via different ISPs. This does not imply any server load balancing feature.

Server load balancing means directing requests to an available backend host. Decide how you want to do this. When the application is HTTP based, extremely common to do this via a reverse proxy, HAProxy or similar. Or, you can swing IP addresses over to the active host in a scheme usually done with clusters. The latter is more network oriented (rather than a session oriented proxy), and was what you implied by referring to a virtual IP. Also, think about where you want to terminate TLS, to support HTTPS.

Decide on an IP address plan. Provider independent IP addresses are nice when you have them. Otherwise, you will be relying on one ISP's address for the front end. You can switch between provider assigned, but DNS changes are not instant.

Probably this load balancer will be a software implementation in addition to the router. As in, an appliance, probably virtualized. Traditional network gear doesn't do a lot of server load balancing, and if the vendor does that might be a different product than their routers.

Comment: I have a website on 2 real servers with different subnet static IPs. I will map my website www.ABC.com to a Virtually IP. When a hit comes to www.ABC.com, it has to redirect to Server1 or Server2 based on the existing load of requests. I will need https request to retain SSL from load balancer to real server also. So I may need 1 SSL cert for server1, 1 SSL cert for server2 and a 3rd SSL cert for LoadBalancer. Please suggest what would be the best way to do this. Also please let me know if the below Virtual Load Balancer can  handle this.  https://kemptechnologies.com/virtual-load-balancer/

Comment: The flow will be like. https: //ABCD.com goes to https: //Serv1IP. Or https: //Serv2IP.

Comment: Read the documentation and try it. https load balancing is one of the more popular use cases.

Comment: After research I found that a Reverse Proxy is the best option which u suggested. I have decided to go for IIS-ARR reverse proxy load balancer.